# Pyramid debug_toolbar: disabled perfomance tab with Python 2.6, but enabled with python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid, django-debug-toolbar

In fact it is not neccessary for me to have this tab active (I mean my most preferable tabs are sqlalchemy, renderings and request vars), but now I want to optimise my views, so I need this tab enabled. Strange that it works only with Python 3 (on two different computers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the system python and you're using Debian, you might need to install the "python-profiler" package via apt.

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thanks a lot! And thanks much more for Pyramid Framework!!! I'm very glad to get answer from you.